My iOS app, although working, logs "Application context data is nil" on startup. Why?
I've made a trivial app to demonstrate the issue.  Taking the defaults for File -> New->Project... -> App, I replaced ContentView.swift
with the following code and run it on an iPhone 15 Pro (17.5) simulator.  The (to me) mysterious error messages are the same on a physical device with a watch counterpart app installed and otherwise working correctly.
The console output is:

Application context data is nil
Application context data is nil
WCSession counterpart app not installed

import WatchConnectivity

struct ContentView: View {
    let wcManager = WatchConnectivityManager.shared
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        }
    }
}

class WatchConnectivityManager: NSObject {
    static let shared: WatchConnectivityManager = WatchConnectivityManager()
        
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        WCSession.default.delegate = self
        WCSession.default.activate()
    }
}
extension WatchConnectivityManager: WCSessionDelegate{
    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
    }
    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
    }
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    }
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
    }
}

Setting a breakpoint shows "activationDidCompleteWith" is called with error = nil.
What application context data is nil?  The session has only just been activated.  There's been no attempt to send a message at this point.

Does it matter?  You tend to get all sorts of spurious log messages from Apple's internal processes

I don't know if it matters.

It doesn't matter
